# What is a good measure of the effect size of group difference in a multigroup multilevel model?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, effect-size, group-differences

Consider that you have a multilevel model measuring students' mathematics knowledge. The students are nested within classes, and classes are nested within schools. Additionally, we want to examine the effects of whether or not the student is taking extra out-of-school mathematics tutoring.

It's not the case that some classes or schools have tutoring, and some don't. Instead, around 20% of students from every class take extra tutoring. Therefore, this is not just a multilevel model, but a multigroup multilevel model.

I am wondering what is a good measure of the effect size of the difference in math scores between students who take up tutoring and those who don't. So, I am not so much interested in the effects of the levels of the model (i.e. effects of classes and schools one belongs to). Rather, I am interested in seeing to what extent are the students who take up tutoring better at math exams than the students who do not take up extra tutoring.

I am wondering what would be a good measure of the effect size for this scenario.